# Fedora 31 refuses to show desktop icons if I have Wastebasket icon enabled

Tags: fedora, gnome, desktop

I installed the GNOME Desktop Icons extension through GNOME Extensions, but the icons only show up if I don’t allow the Wastebasket icon to display. Why is this, and can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the comments at [extensions.gnome.org](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/), this seems to be a bug. The upstream project is located at Debian's Salsa: https://salsa.debian.org/gnome-team/shell-extensions/gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons, so you could report the issue there.